# In flex, how to have 'justify' text align option

Tags: apache-flex, text, alignment

How to make text in flex justified (text-align option)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the text of your paragraph to be flush on both the right and left sides, which means you want to set the textAlign style to be TextAlign.JUSTIFY (which is really just a static member that maps to the string 'justify'.)  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Short questions, short answer:

```
myLabel.setStyle('textAlign', 'left');
```